# Instances as attributes; trying to make a class an attribute error

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Getting the following error but I see that there is a attribute I made that I set equal to a class I made.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rachel/Desktop/Practice/ch9.py", line 125, in <module>
    new_tesla.battery.describe_battery()
AttributeError: 'ElectricCar' object has no attribute 'battery'
```

This is the code.

```
class Battery():
    """Model batter for a electric car"""
    def __init__(self,battery_size = 70):
        self.battery_size = battery_size
    def describe_battery(self):
        """print statement about battery size"""
        print("This car has a " + str(self.battery_size) + "-kWh battery.")
class ElectricCar(Car):
    """Represent a electric car"""
    def __init___(self,make,model,year):
        """
        Initialize attributes of the parent class,
        then initialize attributes specific to electric car
        """
        super().__init__(make,model,year)
        self.battery = Battery()

new_tesla = ElectricCar('Big tesla',"model Z",'2020')
new_tesla.battery.describe_battery()
```

Edit: added code for class Car

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self,make,model,year):
        """Initializes attributed to describe a car."""
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0   # default value
        # takes the parameters and stores them as attributes that will be associated with instances
        # made from this class

    def descriptive_name(self):
        """Describes car"""
        print("Make is " + self.make.title() + ", model is " + self.model.title() + " from the year " + self.year)

    def read_odometer(self):
        """Reads odometer"""
        print("This car has " + str(self.odometer_reading) + " miles on it.")

    def update_odometer(self, mileage):
        """
        Set odometer to different value
        Reject change if odometer is rolled back
        """
        if mileage >= self.odometer_reading:
            self.odometer_reading = mileage
        else:
            print("cannot roll back odometer.")
    def fill_gas(self):
        print('Glug glug....')

    def increment_odometer(self,miles):
        """Add the given amount to the odometer reading."""
        if miles > 0:
            self.odometer_reading += miles
        else:
            pass
```

I am pretty sure I am doing this right. I copied the code straight out of crash course python. I see that I did make the class a attribute.. have no idea whats going wrong.

Comment: where's the code for 'Car'?

Comment: You have too many underscores in `__init___`.

Comment: Also, change `class Battery():` to `class Battery:`. (but that's not the cause of the error)

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it and it works. Wow I missed such a tiny detail, I guess trained eyes can see it haha. Also thank you for the () tip! is the parenthesis only needed when you want the child class to inherit a parent class?

Comment: Yes, in Python 3, `class A:` is a shortcut that is equivalent to `class A(object):`.

Answer (score -1):

```
class ElectricCar(Car):
"""Represent a electric car"""
def __init___(self,make,model,year):
    """
    Initialize attributes of the parent class,
    then initialize attributes specific to electric car
    """
    Car.__init__(self, make, model, year)
    self.battery = Battery()
```

or

```
class ElectricCar(Car):
    """Represent a electric car"""
def __init___(self,make,model,year):
    """
    Initialize attributes of the parent class,
    then initialize attributes specific to electric car
    """
    super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(make, model, year)
    self.battery = Battery()
```

second method, class Car(object)

Comment: None of the changes suggested in this answer are necessary, and none of them fix the bug.

Comment: I try his code,and I found the error is the line (super().__init__(make,model,year)),Then i change it,the code goes well.

Comment: That's because you tried to run Python 3 code on Python 2 (and because you took out the actual, unrelated source of the bug without realizing it in your tests).